# jquery variable not updating out of resize

Tags: jquery

Consider the following code segment :-

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
  var window_width=$(window).width();
  function myresize(){
    window_width=$(window).width();
    console.log('============window width='+window_width+' =========================');
  }
  $(window).resize(myresize);
  if (window_width<options.hide_width){
    console.log('============window width='+window_width+' =========================');
  }
  else
  {
    console.log('============window width='+window_width+' =========================');
  });`
```

When I resize the correct value for window_width gets logged. However, the conditional code underneath still behaves as if I have not resized. If I then do a page refresh the correct condition runs, and logs the new window size.

So my question is, **why is the correct conditional part not running after a resize if the value of window_width is correct**?

I am still fairly new to jquery, so please forgive my ignorance if it's something daft, but I am going around in square circles here, and have been unable to google any sort of answer. The numerous similar questions about this on SO are also getting me nowhere.

Thank you.

Comment: how does it works looks like having syntax error.

Comment: I created a http://jsfiddle.net/1vqfv5px/ for easier debugging.

Comment: options.hide_width = what?

Comment: The options are passed as a paramater from php. This is part of a wordpress plugin. So options.hide_width is just a variable, currently set at 960. that part of it works 100%, so to test just replace it with any number representing a width.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess I got what you mean.

The if-else condition will run once only when document ready after event listener binded to window:
    $(window).resize(myresize);

If you want the if-else clause run whenever window is resizing, please put whole if-else into myresize function.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var window_width = $(window).width();

    function myresize() {
        console.log(window_width);
        window_width = $(window).width();
        console.log('============window width=' + window_width + ' =========================');

        if (window_width < options.hide_width) {
            console.log('============window width=' + window_width + ' =========================');
        } else {
            console.log('============window width=' + window_width + ' =========================');
        }
    }

    $(window).resize(myresize);
});
```

Comment: Close. I moved the conditional parts into myresize, but something is still not right. It's works if I maximise a window, i.e. the correct part runs, but it does not work whenever I 'restore down', i.e. make the window smaller. I am still looking into it though.... perhaps I missed something.

Comment: If you hardcode options.hide_width to 960 that: if (window_width < 960), it works. http://jsfiddle.net/8Lyoy7jt/  I think it is a scope problem(variable is not in current clause/function, might be not passed, note  declared at that moment etc.). Try to log options.hide_width inside myresize fn to see it is available to use.

Comment: Nah, I tried your suggestion, but options.hide_width is logging correctly no matter where I put it.

Comment: I am almost sure your answer above is spot on, and the problem now is with the rest of my code. Just Give time to check it out and confirm. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Ok, confirmed your answer is working. I just need to fix another problem and I am on my way. Thanks again. Bottom line is moving the code into myresize sorted the problem.